# How to post a file and a json with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, file, curl, cxf, jax-rs

I'm using Apache CXF and have the following JAX-RS POST service:

```
@POST
@Path("/{id}/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(@PathParam("id") final String id,
        @Multipart(value = "file") final InputStream inputStream,
        @Multipart(value = "body") final SomeDTO dto);
```

I can successfully call the service with curl this way:

```
curl -F file="@filetoparse.csv;type=text/csv" -F body='{"time": "2000-01-02T15:11:00-0700","employeeId": "e1"};type=application/json'   http://localhost:8085/my-app/1.0.0/somepath/1/upload
```

I tried to call the service with a html form. But with no luck. Looking at the chrome console, I can see that only 1 Request Payload is being sent, the file. The JSON is not being sent.

So I'm going to try with a jquery post.
How can I send two Request Payloads with jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could make it work with this call:

```
var data = new FormData();

myFile = $("#myId").find("input[type='file']")[0].files[0];
var fileblob = new Blob([myFile], { type: "text/csv"});
data.append('file', fileblob);

var myJson = $("#myId2").find("textarea").val();
var jsonblob = new Blob([myJson], { type: "application/json"});
data.append('body', jsonblob);

$.ajax({
    url: 'someUrl',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST'
}).done(function (data, statusText, xhr) {
    var status = xhr.status;
    //Do something depending the status
});
```